# VS Error loading expression evaluator dll

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I get this error when trying to debug an application in VS.
What does this mean?
I can bypass this error and step-through code but I won't be able to view expressions and contents of variables by hovering over them. This is very annoying because I can't use OutputDebugString so I've been using MessageBox and a txt file to write my errors to. I've tried a repair twice to no resolve and I could only find very little information about this problem through google. If I can't find an answer here, I'll post a microsoft ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem occured to my VS2015 too, after a major update (the update 2, KB3151378). After extensive search on google, I found the **cppdebug.dll** (under Your\path\to\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\Debugger) is the most suspicious culprit. The version of cppdebug.dll after the update is 14.0.25132.0. I managed to solve the issue by copying from another VS2015 (before the update, fortunately) a cppdebug.dll with an older version (14.0.25008.0) to replace the faulty one. Now the debugging is working again.

Lesson learned: finish your current project before updating your VS.

Comment: Hey could you please do me a favor and upload that dll for me?

Comment: Here is the link to my working cppdebug.dll:https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6mEV-kzZjrbQzhPbmdXT3N6Q2s

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem under VS2015, and found the following solution:

Under Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> General, you should see an option "Use Native Compatibility Mode". Enable it.

I guess, this means that some debugging mode is enabled that is compatible to older VS versions and that might lack of some goodies that came with VS 2015 (?), but for me, it works!

There's another, similar option, "Use Managed Compatibility Mode", that has a similar effect on managed applications.

Comment: For a windows application, the option 'Use Managed Compatibility Mode' saved me.

Answer (score 0):

For those using VS2017 with JIT debugging, you might have to install the related workloads (e.g. .NET desktop development) to be able to load the Expression Evaluator DLL.